# Turn time char array into integers in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, time

I don't use C regularly so this is kind of tricky for me even though I'm sure it's a pretty simple task. I've been trying to research how to do this and I don't think I'm phrasing it correctly every time I search.

I need help figuring out how to turn the numbers in a char array into integers.

Basically, I'll have a char array like "1:09pm", "11:12AM", "11:12am", etc.

I'm trying to figure out how to separate the three things so I can figure out 
(1) the number of hours, 
(2) number of minutes, and 
(3) whether it's AM or PM (caps or not)

So far I think I have a way to get the first number:

```
char *time = arg[1]; // arg[1] is "1:09pm", etc
char *hours = strtok(time, ":");
int hours = atoi(hours);
```

From there, I'm not 100% sure what to do. Is there some sort of regular expression type parsing function that'll go from ":" to an alphabet character?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I believe that there are libraries for this sort of thing: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Low_002dLevel-Time-String-Parsing.html#Low_002dLevel-Time-String-Parsing Assuming this is some sort of assignment, I am guessing this would not qualify as a good answer...

Comment: @drew_w well it's a start! I'm just trying to figure out what functions I should be using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just building on what you started...

```
char *time = arg[1]; // arg[1] is "1:09pm", etc
char *hours = strtok(time, ":ap");
char *mins = strtok(NULL, ":ap");
int ihours = atoi(hours);
int imins = atoi(mins);
if (strchr(time, 'a') == NULL) hours += 12;
```

The second call to strtok will find the next instance of any character in the token string you provide.  So the second call will find either an 'a' or a 'p'.  The atoi method will ignore alpha characters when it sees the a or p.  The if statement is to scale your hours by am or pm.

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this earlier, but this is super helpful! Thank you so much @jcyost!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with a simple `sscanf()` call.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int hour, minute;   
    char c, time[] = {"1:23AM"};    

    // scan time for an int, a ':', another int and any char before another char.
    sscanf(time, "%d:%d%c%*c", &hour, &minute, &c);

    // to 24h format
    hour += (tolower(c) == 'p') ? 12 : 0;

    // just checking
    printf("%d h, %d min.\n", hour, minute);

}
```

`sscanf()` (and `fscanf()` too) is a very powerful tool, you can do all lot of parsing with it.

Take a look:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#if _WIN32 || _WIN64
  #define sicmp(s1, s2) stricmp(s1, s2)
#else
  #define sicmp(s1, s2) strcasecmp(s1, s2)
#endif

enum meridian { AM, PM };

bool t_sep(/* in */const char *str, /* out */int *h, int *m, int *meridian){
    char ampm[3];
    if(sscanf(str, "%d:%d%2s", h, m, ampm)==3){
        if(sicmp(ampm, "AM")==0){
            *meridian = AM;
            return true;
        }
        if(sicmp(ampm, "PM")==0){
            *meridian = PM;
            return true;
        }
        //and range check
    }
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    const char *test[] = {"1:09pm", "11:12AM", "11:12am"};
    int i, numOfTest = sizeof(test)/sizeof(*test);
    int h, m, ampm;
    for(i=0;i<numOfTest;++i){
        if(t_sep(test[i], &h, &m, &ampm))
            printf("%02d:%02d\n", h + ampm * 12, m);
    }
    return 0;
}
```